# How can I quickly browse text files in a directory (e.g. by pressing left and right arrow keys)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, text-editors

I'm working on a job that involves ~80,000 text files in a folder, and I want to be able to quickly browse through them (for example, by pressing the left and right arrow keys on my keyboard, or even holding them down to continuously skim through the different files).

In other words, I'd like the kind of functionality that the photo viewer has, where I can press the arrow keys to switch between photos, except I want that for text files.

Is there any way to do this on Windows 10?

Comment: What about using the explorer preview pane?

Comment: @LotPings That is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.  If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: yep explorer preview pane is the perfect solution for this..I completely forgot about it...used to use it years back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Explorer Preview Pane.

When in the folder with the text files, go to View --> Preview pane.

Then when you click on a file in the folder, you can use your down / up arrow keys to switch to the next / previous file.

[image]

Comment: Except that the font in that preview pane was TOO LARGE for me! Oh, and you know why? Because I changed the font in Notepad. :-) So this preview pane is using the font you have configured in the Notepad application. Funny, but works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such way, but you could try this if it helps:

Select multiple text files at once, right click and select open.

Then simply press alt + F4 as you go through the files